# Can multi module maven project be considered a Microservice?

Tags: java, docker, maven, microservices

I have a question to ask. Some time ago I was working on a project as a junior Java developer. It was a Java Enterprise Web App which uses Spring and Hibernate frameworks. I didn't completely understand the architecture of the project and I had only a small contribution to the project. But it was a multi module maven project and each module was built and deployed as a WAR file separately in the Oracle Web logic 12c. They didn't use docker and I don't know how the modules interact with each other (it might be REST or something). My question is: can we consider this type of multi module maven project that each module is deployed separately a microservice architecture?

Also, could you please inform me about a good book to start learning microservice architecture in Java?

Comment: It is not about size but about responsibility

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Not using docker (or any other containers) does not necessarily mean that the architecture is not a micro-services based one. It can perfectly be as you are describing: multiple "WARs" (modules) communicating through REST APIs or gRPC or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this is certainly microservice architecture, as a single overall application is broken out into seperate running instanes. Spring makes it very easy for separate microservices to communicate with each other via REST APIs, Eureka and Feign Clients. Idk about a book on microservices, but a simple project is always a good way to learn. Those might not sound meaningful to you but i recommend finding a simple eureka feign client tutorial online, and doing your own version of it. I did that and was able to deploy the same spring service to both my laptop and a pi, call these microservices repeatedly from another microservice on my laptop (the method i was calling just returned the environment hostname) and see that eureka was passing the call to each one in turn, giving me alertnating results. This demonstrates how easy you can horizontally scale using this architecture (i.e. if i need more power i can just keep deploying new instances of that getHostname microservice and no matter what device they are on eureka can link them up)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say about architecture style with given information.
Docker or without docker is not a constraint for microservice architecture style.
If you want to study microservice in Java than I suggest that you may refer to "Microservice Patterns - Chris Richardson".